# limit results of twitter.lookupUser method?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

in the twitter4j library: 
Is there a way to reduce the number of results for the twitter.lookupUser method? i.e. only return certain fields or even only fields that are not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually already found the answer. So for people who are looking for the same thing:

if you use the lookupUser method a list of Users gets returned. so then you can use all of the User methods on that list. For example getLocation, which only returns the location of the users in the list.